# WCF - Transport Authentication - Get Credentials of Authenticated User

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, credentials

I have a `NetTcpBinding` with `SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential`.

`Transport.ClientCredentialType` is set to `MessageCredentialType.Windows`, but I'm considering `MessageCredentialType.UserName`.

Then there's a class DataStoreServerProxy for fetching database data which implements IDataStoreContract.

It contains methods such as this one:

```
Private Function Common_IDataStoreContract_ModifyData(ByVal ParamArray dmlStatements As ModificationStatement()) As ModificationResult Implements IDataStoreContract.ModifyData
        Return wrappedDataStore.ModifyData(dmlStatements)
    End Function
```

In order to get to that DB point, user must have already supplied the credentials. The question is, how to obtain them in those methods? Depending on the user name, I have to decide whether to allow access to some tables or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username can be retrieved using `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name`