# Can client credentials be read from within service implementation?

Tags: c#, wcf, http

I am hosting a soap webservice via an instance `iHost` of `ServiceHost`; authentication is configured as

```
HttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
iHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode 
    = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
iHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator
    = new CustomValidator();
```

The hosting itself works as desired, however I also would like to access the client credentials from within the hosted service itself. Can this be achieved with the current authentication settings or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with the help of a coworker. Username can be accessed via `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name`; the question can be seen as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244735/wcf-transport-authentication-get-credentials-of-authenticated-user).